# Can anyone please help me to modify the code so that it runs faster?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

this is a program for a blindspot detection system using 4 ultrasonic and 2 ir sensors.
can someone help me in modifyng the code so that this runs faster?

```
#include<LiquidCrystal.h> 
#define trigbl 14
#define echobl 15
#define trigbr 16
#define echobr 17
#define trigfl 18
#define echofl 19
#define trigfr 8
#define echofr 9
#define bl 10
#define br 11
long durationbl;
long durationbr;
long durationfl;
long durationfr;
int distancebl;
int distancebr;
int distancefl;
int distancefr;
int irr;
int irl;
int a;
int b;
LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2);
void setup()
{
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode(trigbl, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echobl, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigbr, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echobr, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigfl, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echofl, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigfr, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echofr, INPUT);
  pinMode(bl, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(br, INPUT_PULLUP);
}
void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(trigbl, LOW);
  delay(2);
  digitalWrite(trigbl, HIGH);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(trigbl, LOW);
  durationbl = pulseIn(echobl, HIGH);
  distancebl = durationbl * 0.034 / 2;
  int a1=distancebl;
  digitalWrite(trigbr, LOW);
  delay(2);
  digitalWrite(trigbr, HIGH);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(trigbr, LOW);
   durationbr = pulseIn(echobr, HIGH);
   distancebr = durationbr * 0.034 / 2;
  int a2=distancebr;
  digitalWrite(trigfl, LOW);
  delay(2);
  digitalWrite(trigfl, HIGH);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(trigfl, LOW);
  durationfl = pulseIn(echofl, HIGH);
  distancefl = durationfl * 0.034 / 2;
  int a3=distancefl;
  digitalWrite(trigfr, LOW);
  delay(2);
  digitalWrite(trigfr, HIGH);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(trigfr, LOW);
  durationfr = pulseIn(echofr, HIGH);
  distancefr = durationfr * 0.034 / 2;
  int a4=distancefr;
  irl =digitalRead(bl);
  irr =digitalRead(br);
  lcd.setCursor(1, 0);          
  lcd.print("RL  RR  FL  FR");
  if (a1<30 && irl==0)
  {
  a=0;
  }
  else
  {
    a=1;
  }
   if (a2<30 || irr==0)
  {
  b=0;
  }
  else
  {
    b=1;
  }
   if  (a==1 && b==1 && a3>30 && a4>30)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    lcd.print("No Obstacle    ");
  }
  else if ( a==0 && b==1 && a3>30 && a4>30)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    lcd.print("XX            ");
  }
  else if ( a==1 && b==0 && a3>30 && a4>30)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    lcd.print("    XX        ");
  }  
  else if ( a==1 && b==1 && a3<30 && a4>30)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    lcd.print("        XX    ");
  }  
   else if ( a==1 && b==1 && a3>30 && a4<30)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    lcd.print("            XX");
  }  
  else if ( a==0 && b==0 && a3>30 && a4>30)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    lcd.print("XX  XX        ");
  }  
  else if ( a==1 && b==0 && a3<30 && a4>30)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    lcd.print("    XX  XX    ");
  }  

  else if ( a==0 && b==1 && a3<30 && a4>30)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    lcd.print("XX      XX    ");
  }
  else if ( a==0 && b==1 && a3>30 && a4<30)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    lcd.print("XX          XX");
   }
  else if ( a==1 && b==0 && a3>30 && a4<30)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    lcd.print("    XX      XX");
  }    
  else if ( a==0 && b==0 && a3<30 && a4>30)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    lcd.print("XX  XX  XX    "); 
  }
  else if ( a==1 && b==1 && a3<30 && a4<30)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    lcd.print("        XX  XX");
  }      
  else if ( a==1 && b==1 && a3>30 && a4<30)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    lcd.print("XX  XX      XX");
  }  
  else if ( a==1 && b==0 && a3<30 && a4<30)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    lcd.print("XX      XX  XX");
   }  
  else if ( a==1 && b==0 && a3<30 && a4<30)
  {
    lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    lcd.print("    XX  XX  XX");
  }  
  else if ( a==0 && b==0 && a3<30 && a4<30)
  {
        lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
        lcd.print("Call Help ......  ");
  }  
}
```

Comment: Remove the delays...?

Comment: @Majenko those delays are to generate pulses for ultrasonic sensors.

Comment: hint: observe the result of these two commands to give you an idea how to shorten all the `else if` blocks ...... `lcd.print("abc");  lcd.print("123");`

Answer (score 6):

You may want to check the datasheet of your sonar sensors to see what is
the recommended trigger pulse duration. On a typical HC-SR04, it is ten
**micro**seconds, not **milli**seconds. So use `delayMicroseconds(10);`.

If your program runs really slowly, the culprit is most probably
`pulseIn()`. This function will wait for an incoming pulse and, if there
is no incoming pulse, it waits one full second before timing out. This
can be simply fixed by providing a third argument to `pulseIn()`, which
is the desired timeout in microseconds. Set it to something reasonable,
maybe around 25,000 µs for a maximum detection range of 4 m.